# compilation error while defining a variable scope

Tags: perl

Could someone kindly point me why this snippet is not compiled:

```
my $crond = "/etc/init.d/crond";
if( -e $crond ) {
    my $d = "d";
}
my $crond = "/etc/init.d/cron$d";
```

Error:

```
"my" variable $crond masks earlier declaration in same scope at /home/andrew/sandbox/processes2cron.pl line 27.
Global symbol "$d" requires explicit package name at /home/andrew/sandbox/processes2cron.pl line 27.
```

I tried different variations with 'my' but still the scope is defined uncorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: You can say [`use diagnostics;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) to produce more verbose warnings/errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $crond = "/etc/init.d/crond";
my $d;
if( -e $crond ) {
    $d = "d";
}
$crond = "/etc/init.d/cron$d";
```

It's just as the error message says. You're redeclaring `$cron` within the same scope, and `$d` is only defined within the `if` block, so the compiler expects `$d` to be a global variable when you use it on the last line, and complains when it can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

You have already declared the variable `$crond` in the first line of your code. By re-declaring it on line 5, you will lose the previous value. In this case, removing the `my` on line 5 will stop the warning.

The variable `$d` is declared within the scope of the if block. This means that it is only accessible until the end of the if block. You then try to refer to it outside the if block, which causes the error. To fix this, declare `$d` before the if statement in the outer scope.